# SWI-Prolog library `assoc:get_assoc` won't unify

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using library `assoc` from SWI-Prolog. Here's a query which confuses me:

```
?- empty_assoc(E), put_assoc(K, E, V, E2), get_assoc(key, E2, 2).
false.
```

Why doesn't this unify?
I'd expect it to unify with

```
E = t,
K = key
V = 2,
E2 = t(key, 2, -, t, t).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`put_assoc/4`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=put_assoc/4) predicate must be called with a bound key and value. Try e.g.

```
?- empty_assoc(E), put_assoc(key, E, 2, E2), get_assoc(key, E2, V).
E = t,
E2 = t(key, 2, -, t, t),
V = 2.
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need to find another solution/lib then, since I need to be able to reason about symbolic variables too.